# why other project reference is not showing in namespace

Tags: asp.net

I have three projects in one solution (ASP.NET)

1. ECL.BIZ.LOGIN
2. ECL.MODEL.LOGIN
3. ECL.UI

When I added a reference to other projects in ECL.UI project, namespace is not available in using keyword. My all projects are set to .NET Framework 4 (not ClientProfile).

Why is this happening?

Note: It was working earlier smoothly, it is happening since I deleted ECL.UI project and recreate it again. After then, I still can not find namespace of other projects.

I am using Visual Studio 2012

Comment: Did you add the references again after deleting?

Comment: yes..i did for sure...if i didn't I would not have posted this question for wasting your time

Answer (score 0):

The answer of my question is:
We have to switch between target frameworks. As I am using Visual Studio 2012, I switched my target framework to .NET 4.5 for all projects and add the reference for required projects and switch back to .NET 4 again for all projects at same time. Then it works absolutely fine as I expected.

*Note: I don't know why it is not working while all other projects are set to same framework even after recreating one of the project. However the above trick worked for me. If anyone having this weird problem after deleting one of their project and recreating it again, you can try the above on your own. Thanks to all*